# Prerendering causes a SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, module

I'm trying to execute `prerender.ts` as [seen here](https://blog.strongbrew.io/prerendering-angular-apps/) to prerender my Angular code, but when I try and execute it using **`ts-node prerender.ts`**, I get the error:

> import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
>       ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)

What is the proper way to execute this from NodeJS? Here is what `prerender.ts` looks like:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppPrerenderModuleNgFactory } from './dist-prerender/main.bundle';

const distFolder = './dist';
const index = fs
    .readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `${distFolder}/index.html`), 'utf8')
    .toString();

// we could automate this based on the app.routes.ts file but
// to keep it simple let's just create an array with the routes we want
// to prerender
const paths = [
    '/about',
    '/brews',
    '/consultancy'];
enableProdMode();

// for every route render the html and save it in the correct folder
paths.forEach(p => renderToHtml(p, distFolder + p));

// don't forget to overwrite the index.html as well
renderToHtml('/index.html', distFolder);

function renderToHtml(url: string, folderPath: string): void {
  // Render the module with the correct url just 
  // as the server would do
  renderModuleFactory(AppPrerenderModuleNgFactory, {
    url,
    document: index
  }).then(html => {
    // create the route directory
    if (url !== '/index.html') {
    fs.mkdirSync(folderPath);
    }
    fs.writeFile(folderPath + '/index.html', html,  (err =>  {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(`success`);
    });
  });
}
```

**Update**: I found that if I used `tsc` to transpile `prerender.ts` to JavaScript first and then executed that with node, I could get past this error. However, I started getting an error which I think is indicative of this code not running within the context of ngZone. So the code is still not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#import-statements):

> Current node.js stable releases do not support ES modules. Additionally, ts-node does not have the required hooks into node.js to support ES modules. You will need to set "module": "commonjs" in your tsconfig.json for your code to work.

Thus, pass below compiler option:

`ts-node --compiler-options '{"module": "commonjs"}' prerender.ts`

Of course, you can just include `"module": "commonjs"` in your (root) tsconfig.json file under `"compilerOptions"`. This way you only have to execute:

`ts-node prerender.ts`